# Why won't changing this value work?

Tags: c

So I'm trying to change the value at x[2] from 0 to 8 using a method, the way I have this isn't working. How can I do this? I tried searching around but came to no avail.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

 void changevar(int* x){
    int* y;
    y = &x[2];
    y = 8;
 }
 int main(int argc, char** argv){
    int* c;
    c = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int));
    printf("here %d\n", c[2]);
    changevar(&c);
    printf("here %d\n", c[2]);
    free(c);
}
```

EDIT: I'm new to pointers

Comment: You allocate space for one integer, but access a third in a "buffer". The behavior of your code is undefined, there is no "fixing" it.

Comment: 1) `c[2]` is undefined behavior. 2) `changevar(&c)` is a constraint violation (i.e. non-compilable). `changevar` expects an `int *` argument. You are passing an `int **` argument. 3) `y = 8` is a constraint violation (i.e. non-compilable). You are not allowed to assign arbitrary integers to pointers.

Comment: @AnT I fixed that, thanks for pointing that out! I originally had the parameter has (int** x) for changevar. Do you know how I can change the of x[2] though?

Comment: It is supposed to be `*y = 8`. Or simply `x[2] = 8` without any `y` at all. The previous points still stand though.

Comment: @AnT thank you! I just got into C programming and these pointers can get out of hand! Have been programming in python and such for years haha.

Comment: you need to `malloc(sizeof(int) * 3);` at least if you want to access `c[2]`

Comment: If your compiler shouts at you, you should listen. `y = 8;` is assigning and integer value to a pointer variable. At least you should get a warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need to allocate enough space:

```
c = malloc(3 * sizeof(int));
```

Notice that [I didn't cast the return value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/478288).

The values are *not* initialized to zero. They can be anything ("undefined"). You can clear it with:

```
memset(c, 0, 3 * sizeof(int));
```

Next, you'll need to pass this value *as is* to your function. (It's already a pointer, after all.)

```
changevar(c);
```

Within your function, you'll need to dereference the address to access it:

```
*y = 8;
```

Those are the errors I see.

Answer (score 0):

So there are two issues that are standing out to me.

1. You're only allocating memory for one `int` in your `malloc` call but trying to access memory that would suggest you allocated a minimum space for 3 `ints`.
2. Your function's parameter is supposed to be a `int*`, however with `changevar(&c)` you're passing in a `int**` because you giving the address of a pointer.

To fix these only a couple of changes need to be made...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

 void changevar(int* x){
    x[2] = 8; // <-- can be simplified to this one line
 }

 int main(int argc, char** argv){
    int* c;
    int amt = 3; // <-- number of ints you want to be able to have space for
    c = malloc(sizeof(int) * amt); // <-- multiply the size and the amount you want
    printf("here %d\n", c[2]);
    changevar(c); // <-- remove the '&' from the argument to just pass the pointer 'c'
    printf("here %d\n", c[2]);
    free(c);
}
```

The output becomes:

```
here 0
here 8
```

Answer (score 0):

Garbage values are being printed because size of array `c` is 1.

```
c = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int));
```

will create an array `c` of size 1.

`c[2]` is a garbage value. (In most systems, 0 is printed instead of a garbage number.)

Your `&c[2]` and `y` do not refer to the same address.

What you want to do is probably this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void changevar(int** x){
    *(*x+2)=8;
}
 int main(int argc, char** argv){
    int* c;
    c = (int*) malloc(3*sizeof(int));
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
        c[i]=0;
    }
    printf("here %d\n", c[2]);
    changevar(&c);
    printf("\nhere %d\n", c[2]);
    free(c);
}
```

Prints:

```
here 0
here 8
```